# DIV over or absolute on JQUERY accordion

Tags: jquery-ui, css-position, accordion

I´m using the JQUERY UI Accordion with full height and width.
All ok with that. But, when I try to put a DIV (cover) above all, it appears BEHIND the accordion. I tried all (all I can or know) and more, but nothing happened. The same result.

Example:
For Style

```
#cover{
  position: absolute;
  top: 123px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

For HTML

```
<body>
<div id="cover"></div>
...
THE REST
...
```

Anyone had this problem or know HOW TO fix it?
Thanks you!

Answer (score 1):

Try adding z-index

```
#cover{
  position: absolute;
  top: 123px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 10000;
}
```

On the other elements that are going to be behind it you can make their z-index lower.

Comment: If you could mark my answer as correct and vote me up I would appreciate that. I will vote you up as well.